# Outlook 2010 on Exchange 2010. Shared calender has stopped working

Tags: exchange, outlook

Okay, first question from me, we are running exchange server 2010, with everyone on outlook 2010, we have a couple of accounts created used only for their outlook calendars, (called left board room and right board room) used to book in meetings. this was and had been working fine for months, now suddenly, outlook say :-
Cannon open the free/busy information. Microsoft Exchange is not available. Either there are network problems or your exchange server is down for maintenance.

But I know that the server is fine, as everyone else is fine and all mail is going through.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: type? standard mailbox or resource mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Right, I managed to fix it, thankyou 'THE CLEANER', as I didn't know what sort f account it was, I thought id try and find out, after some diffing around, I found the mailboxes, in the server manger, but they were disconnected - then I figured it out, my co-worker must have deleted the old accounts they were originally attached to!!!! So I created a couple of blank users, called them 'appropriate' names and reconnected the mailboxes, all working now!!!!!!!!